# English word for a triangle in spherical geometry with three right angles?

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry, translation-request, mathematical-french

French has the word [*trirectangle*](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=trirectangle&dicoid=LITTRE1872) and Italian the word *trirettangolo*, which is a term of spherical geometry meaning a triangle with 3 right angles. What is the corresponding English word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that *trirectangle* is being used as an adjective in that source, not a noun: *des triangles trirectangles*.

The English equivalent appears to be *trirectangular (spherical) triangles*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it's only an adjective in French. It's a noun in Italian…

Comment: Which is the adj. and which the noun in "_trièdres trirectangles_" (= "cube corner" according to [this](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/tri%C3%A8dres%20trirectangles))?

Comment: @Geremia Ah, good question. Your link shows it as an adjective in the definition, but as a noun in the examples. (It's therefore perhaps not the most reliable dictionary...) This is because it's both a noun and an adjective: [*trièdre*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tri%C3%A8dre) means both *trihedron* and *trihedral*. So *trièdres trirectangles* is *trirectangular trihedra*. (NB: as a general rule, adjectives come after nouns in French.)